# Using htaccess to remove html but gets error if a subfolder has the same name

Tags: .htaccess

I have this code in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

RedirectMatch ^/(.*?)/$ /$1

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now I have `http://example.com/services.html` which redirects to `http://example.com/services`
It's working perfectly until I created a subfolder which named `services`.
I tried creating index.html in the said subfolder but I got no luck.

How can I have `http://example.com/services` and `http://example.com/services/service1` both working?

Thanks in advance.